# How to implement a kill switch in a native windows program

Tags: windows, kill

We've got issues with our program potentially hanging in certain situations, is there a way to search and destroy your own program with windows calls without using task manager.  It probably wouldn't make sense to include this in the program itself, but as a bundled thing no one would see.

What's the best way to go about doing this, how deep do I need to dig to stop my program and how shallow should I keep to make sure I don't crash the OS?

Comment: And I went up there, I said, "Shrink, I want to kill.  I mean, I wanna, I wanna kill.  Kill.  I wanna, I wanna see, I wanna see blood and gore and guts and veins in my teeth.  Eat dead burnt bodies. I mean kill, Kill, KILL, KILL."  And I started jumpin up and down yelling, "KILL, KILL," and he started jumpin up and down with me and we was both jumping up and down yelling, "KILL, KILL."  And the sargent came over, pinned a medal on me, sent me down the hall, said, "You're our boy." 

-- Arlo Guthrie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a .bat file and put a [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(WS.10).aspx) command in it to forcefully terminate your application. The command would look something like this:

```
taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
```

Comment: Awesome, these other guys couldn't read my mind, but that's what I was looking for, it's a lot simpler than *groan* programming something!

Comment: @Peter Lol, isn't this a programmer's forum?  And I thought you wanted to "implement a kill switch IN a native windows program". :-p

Comment: @mrduclaw That was originally what I wanted, but you have to admin this is way easier!

Comment: Oohh I Fruedian slipped admin... Shame on me twice!

Comment: @Peter Easier might depend on what you're doing.  I was supposing you might want to do this as part of a larger management service (to keep your original software running), and possibly not have extraneous files cluttering the client machine when your management software can just make the API calls itself.  To each his own. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you should probably fix the situation in which it hangs, one way you could have the program kill itself is to spawn a new thread when you launch the app, and have that thread poll the application and kill it if necessary.

[Killing a thread in windows.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write a Windows Service that serves as a Watchdog. You could find your program by it's .exename and then you need some way to determine if it hangs (for example some simple Inter-Process-Communication or even a Client/Server thing) and restart it if necessary.

That is hardly "no one would see" though.

Comment: Not to concerned about people seeing, I just think it would be nice to have our tech support say, go here and click this instead of do CTRL-Alt-Delete and click our product and watch it die... Yes click end task.. yes click it again...

Answer (score 1):

You can terminate a process using [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx). You'll need to determine the target process id using [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(VS.85).aspx) and then call [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) to obtain a handle to the process in order to terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate running processes using the `EnumProcesses()` function.  This will let you search for the process name, and get the PID.  With the PID, you can open a HANDLE to the process which you need in order to call `TerminateProcess()` to kill the hung process.

There's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(VS.85).aspx) of how to use `EnumProcesses` on MSDN.

Some pseudo-code might look something like:

```
EnumProcesses(pidArray, sizeofArray, &bytesReturned);
for(int i=0; i < bytesReturned/sizeof(DWORD); i++) {
  if(getProcessName(pidArray[i]) == "ourProcess"){
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, pidArray[i]);
    TerminateProcess(hProc, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing something from the pstools of sysinternals ?

Comment: Not to sure anyone wants that EULA popping up everything our program crashes on a machine.